# Cannot Set Foreground For TextBox in DataTemplate in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to set the `Foreground` property for a `TextBox` specified in a `DataTemplate` but the call doesn't work.

I have a `UserControl` with the following XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TextBoxColourTest.TextFrameControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:clrtest="clr-namespace:TextBoxColourTest"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditModeTemplate">
            <TextBox Text="Hello"></TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type clrtest:TextFrameControl}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditModeTemplate}"></Setter>
        </Style>

    </UserControl.Resources>

</UserControl>
```

Then I have some XAML that makes use of the TextFrameControl:

```
<Window x:Class="TextBoxColourTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:textBoxColourTest="clr-namespace:TextBoxColourTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <textBoxColourTest:TextFrameControl x:Name="TextFrameControl"></textBoxColourTest:TextFrameControl>
            <Button Content="Red" Click="OnMouseUpRed"></Button>
            <Button Content="Green" Click="OnMouseUpGreen"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then finally the code behind where I have event handlers for the buttons to change the foreground color:

```
    namespace TextBoxColourTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnMouseUpRed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            TextFrameControl.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }

        private void OnMouseUpGreen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            TextFrameControl.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
    }
}
```

When one of the color buttons is clicked then the foreground color does not change.

If I change the code so that I can alter the value of the font family or font size properties then that does work. Also, I've found that if I replace the `TextBox` with a `TextBlock` then the color does change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind the `Foreground` property of the TextBox to that of the UserControl:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EditModeTemplate">
    <TextBox Text="Hello"
        Foreground="{Binding Foreground,
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: That worked, but how did it work? Any pointers would be appreciated. I don't understand why I could alter the font family and size, or I could alter the foreground color if I replaced the TextBox with a TextBlock.

Comment: No idea why the Foreground value is inherited by a TextBlock, but not by a TextBox.